# Decrypt Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

Sorry for being dumb, but I can't figure out how to decrypt encrypted form input.

In my controller I have:

```
$var = Example::create([
  'email' => encrypt($request->email)
]);
```

In my view I'm doing this:

```
@foreach($var as $a)

  $email = $a->email;
  $decrypted_email = decrypt($email);

  {{ $decrypted_email }}

@endforeach
```

But ofc it doesn't work...
Could somebody obviously clarify decrypt function? Thanks!

Comment: Your PHP code in that Blade template isn't being interpreted as PHP, it's being handled as plain text. See the linked thread for how to do PHP in a Blade template.

Comment: Thank you, it was exact problem along with this one - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/daeling-with-decryptexceptioninvalid-data - my email DB field simply was too short (string), so I changed it to (longText)... Thanks!